# SSRS 100% column chart not showing some data

Tags: reporting-services

I have a 100% Column Chart in SSRS showing depots on the x axis and 5 values on the y axis. It doesn't show some of the depots that has values though. I've made sure that nothing is being hidden anywhere and also put the expressions for the values field in the label of the x axis to make sure the values pull through. There are only two depots that has no values but there are about 5 others showing as if there is nothing. When I sort the x axis from a - z it slots all the depots in at the right place, so it does know that there are values in it.

Comment: can you post the output from the dataset that gets passed to the report and the report design.

Comment: Hi Alan. Apologies for the late reply and thanks for your reply.. I ended up uploading it to our server where it then worked. So it is something on my local machine. Not going to worry too much about it for now then.

Comment: no problem. Thanks for getting back, some people don't bother :)